# Document is not deleting in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using NodeJs and MongoDB as a backend service.I am trying to delete document on MongoDB but couldn't delete but sending response deleted. 
This what I have done so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const app = express();

var dburl = process.env.URL;

app.post('/deleteRow', (req,res) => {

MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true}, (err,client) => {

    var myquery = { _id:req.body.postId};

        if(err){

            console.log("Error:", +err);
        }
        else{

            var collect = client.db('abc').collection('xyz');

            collect.deleteOne(myquery, function(err,obj){

                   if(err){

                    console.log("Error".red, +err);
                   }
                   else{

                     res.send("Deleted");  
                   }

            });
        }

    });

});
```

Let me know what I need to correct in above code. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try casting your req.body.postId to an ObjectId

Something like

```
var ObjectID = require(‘mongodb’).ObjectID;
var postId = new ObjectID(req.body.postId);
```

Then use that postId in your deleteOne({}) params

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked but I want to ask one thing do we need to to convert this into ObjectId first before deleting.

Comment: No problem!  Mongo uses ObjectID for it's _id field. What I have found usually is that whichever ID you are using to delete a document (in your case, req.body.postId), it's best to convert it to an ObjectID first, then use it in your query.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.